# how to start with windows API in .net

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want to work on windows API. I have an interest in creating network application that can communicate with web as well. I haven't thought any application yet. But before doing all this . I want to know where to start with. What all I need to start reading.

I have created lot of database interactive applications with window forms. But would like to start with this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the best C# .NET books?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477748/what-are-the-best-c-net-books)

Comment: In my experience the best approach is to come up with an application and then work out how to do it.

Comment: @ChrisF: I have an idea but dont know much. I am looking to create an application that can synchronize the log created by another application after some time interval set by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Windows API methods from .Net, you'll need to use PInvoke to call them. There's a site called [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/) that has samples for how you call many of the APIs so if you know which API you want to call, that's usually the best place to start.

Answer (score 0):

For your use case maybe you dont need API at all. You could use the FileSystemWatcher .net class to react on any changes in a log folder e.g. It reacts on modify/add/delete of files.